# Student discount for Frankfurt Radio Symphony Orchestra

Tags: budget, germany, frankfurt, music

I am a graduate student in the US, and would like to go to a concert of Frankfurt Radio Symphony Orchestra.

Their policy being that one can buy a student discount through their webpage, but one has to show the proof.

If I show them my valid student ID upon entry, would it be all right? I certainly don't want that my entry is denied by not having German student ID or any other reason.

Answer (score 8):

Having used student discounts at various theatres in Germany with a European student ID that did not even state "student" or an expiration date, I'd say your US student ID should be fine if it looks somewhat legit, you look like a university student (agewise) and you have an accompanying photo ID in case the student ID has no photo.

If you are very concerned, have your university print and sign a statement that you are a student, but that is overkill. Even in the worst case, I believe they would make you pay for the price difference only, but don't worry, they won't be as strict.

Comment: @pnuts can you clarify if your comment means _it will work_ or _it will not work_ please?

Answer (score 3):

Student or pupil IDs are not standardized in Germany. Every school and every university has their own thing. Some have cards, some have paper cards. Some of them are laminated, others are not allowed to be laminated<sup>1</sup>. Some have issue dates, some have validity dates or time spans. Most have no picture. Some schools don't even have IDs at all, but they have full A4 papers or they use simply use the local public transport company's ticket type that's reserved for school children.

Because of that chaotic variety, it's very hard for others to check the legitimacy of those IDs. There are student discounts in most theaters, museums, cinemas and swimming pools, and that list continues.

I would say whether they accept it or not is varying. The fact that you're a student in a different country doesn't usually matter. If it says you are a student and it doesn't have an expiration date in the past, you're usually good. Most cashiers don't much give a damn.

What they do sometimes check is if the name matches your gender, so taking your little sister's student ID to get into the movies cheap might not work if you're big, bearded John and the ID says *Jessica*.

A lot of places are fine if you have something that resembles a card that has the word student on it if it's from a different country though. Don't sweat it, and enjoy your visit.

---

<sup>1) Deutsche Bahn would refuse the ticket component of the thin paper student ID from Hannover University if you laminated it yourself because their metallic hologram would not be fully usable any more... or so they said. I know people having to pay fines for taking the train without a valid ticket because they tried protecting their ticket from dirt and crumpling</sup>

Comment: As soon as you wrote *not allowed to be laminated* I was like ‘you’re talking about Hannover, aren’t you?’ xD

Comment: @Jan, yeah that one is ridiculous. And we always needed to carry this huge other paper with the explanation of which kinds of trains are allowed or it wouldn't be valid.

Comment: Well, at least there is no longer a requirement of carrying a paper with which trains are valid. And the simple solution for protecting the thing was to buy a small plastic sleeve wherein to put it so … yeah.